# Shiro's clearCachedAuthenticationInfo is null

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, redis, shiro

When shiro executes clearCachedAuthenticationInfo, the following problems occur:

```
protected void clearCachedAuthenticationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(principals)) {
        // return null
        Cache<Object, AuthenticationInfo> cache = this.getAvailableAuthenticationCache(); 
        if (cache != null) {
            Object key = this.getAuthenticationCacheKey(principals);
            cache.remove(key);
        }
    }

}
```

[click me to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nORNH.png)

Caused the session can not be cleared, seeking solutions

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't link to images of code. Instead describe your problem as precisely and concisely as possible directly in the question text. Have a look at this for a detailed explanation of why images of code are not a good idea: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: It looks like your auth cache is null, so there is nothing to remove.  Can you provide more info on your application?  When a user logs in is the cache populated?